# SQL count distinct values and count null values for all columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, isnull, distinct-values

I have a table called tbl_site with 50 columns. I want to write some SQL code that will count the number of distinct values and the number of null values for each column without having to run a statement for each column.

I understand this would possibly include running a nested query to information_schema.columns but I am unsure on how to construct the query further. Also null values would include values that are '' and ' ' if possible.

The desired output would be the following:

```
Column      | Distinct | Null
site_id     | 100      | 0
sitearea_id | 12       | 0
site_area   | 54       | 5
etc....
```

Comment: What sql engine do you use?

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: I am using MySQL and require the output I have specified above

Answer (score 0):

Try a mixture of count distinct and sum case:

```
SELECT Column, count(distinct Column) as 'Distinct'
,sum(case when Column is null then 1 else 0 end) as 'Null'
FROM  tbl_site
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I noticed it's MySQL after i made a script for SQL Server ... but anyway here is the code in case someone needs it ... or if you get idea from it how to do it

```
declare @position int = 1,
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @columnCnt int,
        @currentColumn nvarchar(50),
        @TableName nvarchar(50) = 'YourTableName',
        @DBName nvarchar(50) = 'YourDbName';

if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyRowCount')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyRowCount
CREATE TABLE #MyRowCount (ColumnName nvarchar(50), DistinctCount int, NullCount int)

set @columnCnt = (select MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                  where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and TABLE_CATALOG = @DBName)

WHILE (@position <= @columnCnt)
BEGIN

    set @currentColumn = (select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                          where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and 
                                TABLE_CATALOG = @DBName and 
                                ORDINAL_POSITION = @position)

    set @sql = 'INSERT INTO #MyRowCount (ColumnName, DistinctCount, NullCount)
                  SELECT ''' + @currentColumn + ''', 
                 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [' + @currentColumn + ']) FROM ' + @TableName + ' where [' + @currentColumn + '] IS NOT NULL), 
                 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TableName + ' where [' + @currentColumn + '] IS NULL)';

    -- print @sql;

    execute (@sql);

    set @position = @position + 1;

END

SELECT * FROM #MyRowCount
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can construct the query using:

```
set @sql = '
select ''[column]'' as col, count(distinct "[column]"), sum("[column]" is null)
from [table] t
';

select group_concat(replace(replace(@sql, '[table]', table_name), '[column]', column_name) separator ' union all ')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = ?;
```

The caveat to this approach is that you need to be sure that your group_concat maximum length value is long enough (the default of 1024 won't get you very far).

Then, you can either copy the query to use `prepare`/`execute` to run it.